# Migrate Kubernetes storage from vSphere to NFS with StatefulSets

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, vmware-vsphere

I'm trying to move all my persistent volumes from vSphere to NFS, I managed to do it for many applications that use `Deployment` kind. All I have to do is:

- Mount the NFS volume to a different path (`/tmp` for example)
- Copy the data from vSphere volume to NFS volume (using `cp` command in the pod)
- Swap the volumes names in
  the `Deployment` definition and finally get rid of the vSphere volume

Now, I have StatefulSets with volumes to be mounted on each pod. This approach won't work since Kubernetes wont let you modify the field `spec.volumeClaimTemplates` in `StatefulSets` definition.

I have 3 replicas and the vSphere volumes were provisioned dynamically, but I have now 3 NFS volumes that I created manually and I want to migrate the existing data to them.

Any idea how to perform this operation?

Comment: Hello abdelhalimresu, could you add sts spec.volumeClaimTemplates section to the question? How did you set up a Kubernetes cluster (cloud, on-premise, k8s version)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero): it's Vmware tool that lets you back up and restore your Kubernetes cluster resources and persistent volumes. You can run Velero with a public cloud platform or on-premises. Velero lets you:

- Take backups of your cluster and restore in case of loss.
- Migrate cluster resources to other clusters.
- Replicate your production cluster to development and testing clusters.